# Inserting a default value into tkinter Entry stops validation

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have been following the validation for Entry boxes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content). The code below is from the answer with the added condition that if the entered value is `'Q'` then the program adds `'test'` to the beginning of the Entry value.

However once this value is inserted, all validation appears to go out of the window and the Entry allows upper-case values. Some testing on my program shows the validation command (`OnValidate` in this case) isn't being called upon any further events of the Entry (key, focusin/out etc).

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        vcmd = (self.root.register(self.OnValidate), 
                '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root, validate="key", 
                              validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def OnValidate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
        if S == "Q":
            self.entry.insert(0,"test")
        # only allow if the string is lowercase
        return (S.lower() == S)

app=MyApp()
```

The reason for me doing this is I want the Entry to display a default value if its value is left empty after any changes that are made by a user. (i.e. my condition would be `if not P` on focusout)

Any ideas how to implement this or what's going wrong in the above much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer completely based on:

> I want the Entry to display a default
> value if its value is left empty after any changes that are made by a
> user.

and hope that this example points you to what you want:

```
import tkinter

def analyze(event=None):
    content = entry_contents.get()
    if content == "":
        entry_contents.set("default")

root = tkinter.Tk()

entry_contents = tkinter.StringVar()
entry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_contents)
entry.grid()

text = tkinter.Text(root, font=("Georgia", "12"))
text.grid()

entry.bind("<FocusOut>", analyze)

root.mainloop()
```

or if a [control variable](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/control-variables.html) wont be of any use to you:

```
import tkinter

def analyze(event=None):
    content = entry.get()
    if content == "":
        entry.insert(0, "default")

root = tkinter.Tk()

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.grid()

text = tkinter.Text(root, font=("Arial", "12", "bold"))
text.grid()

entry.bind("<FocusOut>", analyze)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, have followed this method to get my desired behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

The `validatecommand` option is designed for validation only, not for doing other sorts of things. The behavior you see is the documented behavior.

According to the [official tk documentation on entry validation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7):

> ... The validate option will also set itself to none when you edit the entry widget from within either the validateCommand or the invalidCommand.

(note: tkinter is little more than a wrapper around the tcl implementation of tk. For this reason, the tcl/tk documentation can be used as the definitive guide to the behavior of Tkinter)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the relevant info. I should probably do a bit more reading of tcl/tk as tkinter's appears sparse.